# Comparing two cells from different Excel files

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I am creating a automation code in VBA to compare cells data from in two separate excel files. I daily run the report file from our application and compare if records are in my master file manually If not I insert it, so my macro would be compare code number if my master excel doesn't have then records are automatically inserted and make a highlight in daily report.

These two excel files I have..

1) This is daily report excel file.

```
  Code Number   Code Type   Reason       Date           work start
   NCO3293     Normal   Upgrade      2018-02-14     2018-02-14 
   NCO1123     Normal   Fix      2018-02-14     2018-02-14 
   NCO2032     Normal   Improvement  2018-02-13     2018-02-13 
   NCO1102     Normal   Upgrade      2018-02-14     2018-02-14 
   NCO3042     Normal   Fix      2018-02-14     2018-02-14
```

2) This is my master excel file.

```
  Code Number   Code Type   Reason       Date           work start
   NCO2934     Normal   Upgrade      2018-02-14     2018-02-14 
   NCO4032     Normal   Fix      2018-02-14     2018-02-14 
   NCO3013     Normal   Improvement  2018-02-13     2018-02-13 
   NCO1102     Normal   Upgrade      2018-02-14     2018-02-14 
   NCO3042     Normal   Fix      2018-02-14     2018-02-14
```

As you can see cell number 1 to 3 are different. so I would like to put whole cells to master excel..

```
Sub SNC_Script()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ThisBook As Workbook  'Mster workbook
Dim SNCBook As Workbook   'SNC workbook
Dim c As Range, LR As Long, FR As Long
Dim CheckedOpen As Integer
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

Set ThisBook = ThisWorkbook

'==================================
'Find SNC workbook if it is opened
'==================================
For Each wb In Workbooks
      If Left(wb.Name, 3) = "SNC" Then
        Set SNCBook = wb
        CheckedOpen = 1
      End If
Next

If CheckedOpen <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Can't find SNC files..please open a SNC file"
Else
    Set w1 = ThisBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = SNCBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LR = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With w1.Range("C1:C" & LR)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "RC[-2]&RC[-1]"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    LR = w2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With w2.Range("C1:C" & LR)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "RC[-2]&RC[-1]"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    For Each c In w2.Range("C1", w2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    FR = Application.Match(c, w1.Columns(3), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FR = 0 Then
      c.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 2).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next c
w1.Columns(3).ClearContents
w2.Columns(3).ClearContents

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Can anyone let me know what's my problem in code?
I really appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn't `If FR = 0 Then` be `If Not FR = 0 Then`? What are you doing when `FR` gets a match?

Comment: So, what's the problem with your code? Are you getting an error? What error specifically? Where? Or is it not doing its job? What are you getting vs what you're expecting? Your post is incomplete. Please see [mcve].